# How to write this function in Ramda?

Tags: ramda.js

Like most devs, I'm a long time Stackoverflow visitor, but it's my first time asking a question! I'm *very* stuck trying to rewrite a function in Ramda.

I've been testing myself, to rewrite bits of code, completely point-free, in Ramda. The goal isn't readability, but to improve my understanding of the library.

I want to ramda-fy something like this:

```
([{ commit }, [{ data }]) =>
    (newData) =>
        commit('addSuccess', { newData, oldData: data })
```

I had come up with something like the following

```
curryN(2, converge(call, [
    pipe(nth(0), prop("commit")),
    always("addSuccess"),
    applySpec({
        newData: nthArg(1),
        oldData: pipe(nth(1), prop("data")),
    }),
]))
```

But in fact it doesn't work as I'd expect. This part of the code is part of a much larger pipeline of functions & it *does* work if I `curryN(1, ...)`. But for me, it shouldn't work with `1`

I think I'm too biased towards my attempted solution... so my question is, how would you write the above code, completely point-free, in Ramda?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question fell through the cracks for me.  Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Also, there's one more `[` than `]` in the signature.  Can you fix it to be correct?